# regex matching consecutive characters from start and end

Tags: regex

Im trying to match  a string to that containsthree consecutive characters at the beginning of the line and the same six consecutive characters at the end.
for example
CCC i love regex CCCCCC
the C's would be highlighted from search

I have found a way to find get the first 3 and the last six using these two regex codes but im struggling to combine them
 `^([0-9]|[aA-zZ])\1\1  and ([0-9]|[aA-zZ])\1\1\1\1\1$`
appreciate any help

Comment: Probably just `^([0-9A-Za-z])\1\1.*\1{6}$` would do? Note the difference in how to set up a character class.

Comment: Please share the code. What is the problem with "highlighting"? Also, `[aA-zZ]` is wrong, use `[[:alnum:]]` instead of `[0-9]|[aA-zZ]`.

Comment: And what do you mean with highlight just those B's? You dont want anything else matched?

Comment: yep, exactly that @JvdV, only match the B's

Comment: What are you trying to do with the match? By definition, a regex match comprises contiguous characters, so the characters matched by `.*` are part of it. Can you do what you want with grouped substrings in parentheses? Perhaps you don't need regex at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want just one regular expression to "highlight" only the 1st three characters **and** last six, maybe use:

```
(?:^([0-9A-Za-z])\1\1(?=.*\1{6}$)|([0-9A-Za-z])\2{5}(?<=^\2{3}.*)$)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/GUm3F7/1)

---

- `(?:` - Open non-capture group to allow for alternations;

  - `^([0-9A-Za-z])\1\1(?=.*\1{6}$)` - Start-line anchor with a 1st capture group followed by two backreferences to that same group. This is followed by a positive lookahead to assert that the very last 6 characters are the same;
  - `|` - Or;
  - `([0-9A-Za-z])\2{5}(?<=^\2{3}.*)$` - The alternative is to match a 2nd capture group with 5 backreferences to the same followed by a positive lookbehind (zero-width) to check that the first three characters are the same.

---

Now, if you don't want to be too strict about "highlighting" the other parts, just use capture groups:

```
^(([0-9A-Za-z])\2\2).*(\2{6})$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/BP3Sf7/1). Where you can now refer to both capture group 1 and 3.